# C# setting foreign key

Tags: c#, winforms, persistence

I have a form to input data of an Owner and a Pet into a database. The pet has a foreign key of the owner id, the data of the Owner and the Pet are filled in the same form, so how do I set the owner id in the pet object if the `ownerID` has not been set in the database yet? Or just I have to set the owner in the database first?

Class `Owner` attributes

```
private int32 idOwner;
private String name;
```

Class `Pet` attributes;

```
private int32 Pet;
private int32 idOwner;    // foreign key
private String name;
```

Form

```
Owner owner = new Owner();
owner.Name = this.ownerNameTxt.Text.Trim();
OwnerService.addOwner(owner); // add owner to database

Pet pet = new Pet();
pet.name = this.petNameTxt.Text.Trim();
pet.idOwner = ????????
```

Comment: What are you using ADO.NET or Entity Framework?

Comment: emmm you got me there, Im not sure, I just create a Service folder in the solution and do the connection methods.......I am using System.Data.SqlClient....I dont know if that tell you anything.

Comment: `private Owner _Owner;` you should add this to `Pet` class. I think this would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an identity column `idOwner` which gets generated on insert and you want to set that id in the `Pet` object. Then you need to modify your `OwnerService.addOwner` method in order to select the generated ID from the database and update the owner object.

```
private void addOwner(owner)
{
    // your current logic here but modify to
    // add  ;SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY(); at the end of your insert query.
    // and store it in a local int. eg int ownerID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    owner.idOwner = ownerID;
}
```

Then your form code:

```
Owner owner = new Owner();
owner.Name = this.ownerNameTxt.Text.Trim();
OwnerService.addOwner(owner); // add owner to database

Pet pet = new Pet();
pet.name = this.petNameTxt.Text.Trim();
pet.idOwner = owner.idOwner;
```

Docs for [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx):

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Comment: Like this?                                                                                                                           public static void addOwner(Owner owner)
        {

            String sql = "INSERT INTO Owner (name)"
                    + " VALUES('" + owner.Name + "')";SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY(ownerID);

     owner.idOwner = ownerID;

            connect();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            disconnect();
        }

Comment: @DedalusNine No this has c# syntax errors. Like this: `String sql = "INSERT INTO Owner (name)" + " VALUES('" + owner.Name + "') ;SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY();";`

Comment: @DedalusNine then you need to set the ID to a variable : `int ID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();` then `owner.idOwner = ID;` It that clear ?